# How to set default decoding of filename when receiving a MultipartFile in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Given the following controller in a Spring Boot (v2.5.4) application:

```java
@PostMapping(consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public void upload(@RequestParam(value = FILES_KEY, required = false) MultipartFile multipartFile) {
    System.out.println(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
}
```

If the uploaded `multipartFile` contains an e.g.blank character, then this will be encoded with `%20`. A quick fix is to decode the string like this:

`URLDecoder.decode(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename(), "UTF-8");`.

However I would need to repeat this in all controllers/services where we're dealing wit the `getOriginalFilname()`. Does Spring Boot provide a "central way" to do this decoding?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following annotation for this scenario.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "multipart/form-data" })
```

However, to achieve your goal you can simple keep `@RequestMapping` empty. There is a working sample code form one of my applications mentioned below.

```
/**
 * Responsible for uploading the image for the most recently created book.
 * @param theFile MultipartFile
 */
@PostMapping("/upload")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void uploadImage(@RequestParam("imageFile") MultipartFile theFile) {
    printLog("(REST endpoint) @PostMapping for path - '/upload' (Updating the image for recently created book)");
    bookService.uploadImage(theFile);
}
```

However, I highly motivate you to be specific and follow your pattern by adding  `consumes` to your `@PostMapping`. This is just for your reference.

Hope this answer helped you. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

After several debugging sessions I finally found out that this issue was caused by our interal frontend. This JavaSCript application encoded the filename with `encodeURI()`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

After having removed this function, filenames are consistent between, both, frontend and backend.